# How to make dialog and the top menu remain the same orientation across different languages?

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to keep my app orientation the same orientation as an English user, even though my phone is with Hebrew settings. For the Activities, I'm using the `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` command, but this command does not work for the alert dialogs (the positive and negative buttons are on the left side of the dialog and on the wrong order) and the top menu.
is there a way to force the app keep the orientation?

Comment: there is `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(view, dir)` method, maybe after creating `Dialog` use this method - pass root view of created dialog and set `dir=LayoutDirection.LTR`

Comment: I wrote this line 'ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(dialog.getListView(), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);' and I Recived this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setLayoutDirection(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

try this for dialogs (they appear in new `Window` and params set to `Activity`s window aren't applied, both xml and by code)

```
Dialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(dialog.getWindow().getDecorView(), LayoutDirection.LTR);
dialog.show();
```

before creating dialog (`build()` call) its window isn't created (yet), even layout isn't parsed/drawn, thus now you are getting exception referencing to not-yet-existing view

(`show`ing includes creating step, so you can also try to call `setLayoutDirection` just after `show()` call)

Comment: The text is alined, but the buttons remaind the same